# How to filter data based on datatype?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Given data like this:

```
val my_data = sc.parallelize(Array(
  "Key1, foobar, 10, twenty, 20",
  "Key2, impt, 11, sixty, 6",
  "Key3, helloworld, 110, seventy, 9"))
```

I would like to filter and create a `key,value` RDD like below:

```
key1, foobar
key1, twenty
key2, impt
key2, sixty
key3, helloworld
key3, seventy
```

**What I've tried**

I figured that I can just put the data in a table and let data types be inferred.

```
//is there a way to avoid writing to file???
my_data.coalesce(1).saveAsTextFile("/tmp/mydata.csv") 
val df_mydata = sqlContext.read
.format("com.databricks.spark.csv")
.option("inferSchema", "true") 
.load("/tmp/mydata.csv")
```

The above works such that I've got a table with the correct data types. However, I don't know how to filter on the data types and then create key/value pairs from it.

I could also use `Character.isDigit` instead of creating a schema but still need to know how to filter the key/value pairs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to solve it would be, as you mentioned, to use `Character.isDigit` together with a `split` and `flatMap`. Using your `my_data` as example:

```
val spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()
import spark.implicits._

val df = my_data.map(_.split(",").map(_.trim).toList.filterNot(s => s.forall(_.isDigit)))
  .flatMap{case ((key: String)::tail) => tail.map(t => (key, t))}.toDF("Key", "Value")
df.show()
```

Which will give you something like this:

```
+----+----------+
| Key|     Value|
+----+----------+
|Key1|    foobar|
|Key1|    twenty|
|Key2|      impt|
|Key2|     sixty|
|Key3|helloworld|
|Key3|   seventy|
+----+----------+
```

Here I also converted it into a dataframe, but if you want an rdd you can simply skip that step. for it to work, it's necessary for each row to contain a key and that key should be at the first position in the string.

Hope it helps!

---

**EDIT:**

Breakdown of the commands used.

The first map goes through each string in your rdd, for each string the following is applied (in order):

```
.split(",")
.map(_.trim)
.toList
.filterNot(s => s.forall(_.isDigit))
```

Let's use your first row as an example: `"Key1, foobar, 10, twenty, 20"`. First the row is split by "," whcih will give you an array of strings `Array("Key1", " foobar", " 10", " twenty", " 20")`.

Next is `map(_.trim)` which will trim (remove white spaces before and after the words) each of the elements in the array, the array is also converted into a list (for the case match in the flatMap later on): `List("Key1", "foobar", "10", "twenty", "20")`.

The `filterNot` will remove all strings where all characters is a digit. The `forall` here checks so each character fulfills this condition. This will remove some elements in the list: `List("Key1", "foobar", "twenty")`.

Now, with the filtering done only the grouping after key remains:

```
flatMap{case ((key: String)::tail) => tail.map(t => (key, t))}
```

Here the `key` becomes the first element each row's list, following the example row from before it becomes "Key1". `tail` is simply the rest of the list. Then, for each element that is not the `key` value, we replace it with a tuple `(key, value)`. In other words, each element (except the first, that is `key`) becomes a tuple containing the `key` and itself. `flatMap` is used here as otherwise you would get a list of tuples, not simply tuples as wanted.

The last is converting it to a dataframe with named columns using `toDF("Key", "Value")`, note that this requires the import used in the beginning (`import spark.implicits._`).